# When double clicking on a test in MS Test's test explorer, where does Visual Studio 2015 look for the test code?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, mstest, cppunit

I'm in process of debugging some unit tests that worked in VS2013 and broke in VS2015. There are a number of threads I'm trying to pull debugging this when I came across an odd issue: **When I double click on a test in the Test Explorer, VS2015 has trouble finding the test code.** The error message that appears briefly is:

"Cannot open the following file: MyTestClass.cpp" (MyTestClass is a made up name -- but you get the drift).

This happens for passing and non-passing tests. The project that houses the test code is a VS2012 (v110) project. **My question is, where is VS2015 looking for the test code when I double click on the test in Test Explorer?** It seems like this could be a symptom of why these tests are failing and I'm unsure what VS2015 is doing here.

Some additional information: The test class in question (one example of a class that VS2015 is having trouble finding) resides in the same folder as the .vcxproj file. The output directory for the test project is `$(SolutionDir)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\` and the intermediate directory is `$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\`. I can open the test class .cpp from the solution explorer and view the code. If I right click on a test from the .cpp file directly and click 'Run Test', the tests output claims "No tests found to run". I can run the test by right clicking on it in the test explorer. These are CppUnit tests. This definitely smells like some sort of path issue, but everything seems to be in place, which brings me here. Also, these tests still pass and work in VS2013's IDE without any code or compiler changes.

Comment: Make sure you have a good backup.  Delete the unit test project and create a new one.  Compare the old .sln and .vcxproj files with the new ones.

Comment: I was able to produce some different behavior by creating a new .vcxproj file and tweaking it a little bit to compile in our system (additional include paths, preprocessor directives, library paths) -- but things are still not happy. Tests run in parallel (mostly) pass, not run in parallel (mostly) fail. When run in individual groups they pass. VS still can't find the code on a double click. Unfortunately in this case the solution is being auto-generated by a tool which makes it harder to create a .sln by hand that has all the necessary dependencies. I'll keep pulling on this thread for now.

Comment: A "tool", what could possibly go wrong...  Stop using the tool.

Comment: After creating a blank solution and manually adding all the projects needed to it (instead of using the tool) I'm still experiencing odd failures and the same cannot find/no tests found errors. I'm starting to wonder if it's due to using VS2015 (IDE), with VS2012 .vcxproj files being compiled in v110. I'm still at a loss as to why the same .sln w/ the same .vcxproj files in the VS2013 IDE works fine.